# Select Option using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How do I add in  Please Select One text into the select option? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps.

```
<select id="categoryid" className="form-control" name="category" onChange={handleChange}>
    {categoryData.map(option => (
      <option value={option._id}>{option.title}</option>
       )) }
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<option value={0}>Please Select One</option>` before your map.